# Expat-based xml parsing script not working on Linux, work on Windows

Tags: python, xml, windows, linux, expat-parser

I'm writing a set of tool in python to extract data from some xml files that are generated by a traffic simulation software. As the resulting files can be quite big I use the xml.parsers.expat to parse them.

The issue is, when I run my scripts at work on a Windows XP machine it work perfectly but at home, on Ubuntu 10.10, on the very same file I get the following error :
`ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`

The file was originally encoded in utf-8 and the encoding declared in the  tag was ascii so try to change it to utf-8 (or UTF8 or utf8) without success. As the BOM was absent I tryed to write it, still without success. I also tried to replace Windows line break (CR/LF) by Unix ones (CR).Without any success too.

Also the python's version at work is 2.7.1, on my Ubuntu box it's 2.6.6, but don't think my issue is related that : I upgraded my work computer's Python from 2.6 to 2.7 a few weeks ago without trouble.

As I'm not an expert here, I'm running out of idea, any hint ?

Edit:
After further investigation (I got an headache now, I hate Unicode related trouble) it look like the issue was solved by setting properly the system environment variable LANG, LC_ALL and LANGUAGE to (in my case) "fr_FR.utf-8". I don't understand why they weren't at first neither why now, it work...

I thank you guys for the hand !

Comment: The error message sounds suspiciously like BOM. Is there one?

Comment: I made my original question a little bit clearer about the BOM. The BOM was in the file at first and adding one didn't help.

Comment: @Thomas: Your question contains "the BOM was absent", your comment contains "The BOM was in the file at first"; please clarify.

Comment: Yeah I mistyped: read "The BOM wasn't int the file...".

Comment: @Thomas: Whatever your locale is set to should make absolutely no difference. Saying "the issue was solved by setting properly the system environment variable LANG, LC_ALL and LANGUAGE" is equivalent to "we waved a dead chicken at the volcano and it stopped erupting" :-)

Comment: Hi there, I found finally how my issue was solved. As John says, the env var change wasn't directly the solution. The issue came from a dynamicaly registered error handler that resubmitted the what we want to parse to expat. Under Linux, the script failed at opening the document and a string containing the path was submitted. Maybe with the character set change the script was able to open the document since the path was containing utf-8 characters. I should have investigated the code base more deeply before asking here, and code that change at runtime is bad (I have simplified that now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpts from the documentation:

`xml.parsers.expat.XML_ERROR_INVALID_TOKEN`
Raised when an input byte could not    properly be assigned to a character;    for example, a NUL byte (value 0) in    a UTF-8 input stream.

`ExpatError.lineno`
Line number on which the error was detected. The first line is numbered 1.

`ExpatError.offset`
Character offset into the line where the error occurred. The first column is numbered 0.

The above tends to indicate that you have a problem with the very first byte in your file.

Start with the original file, the one that worked on Windows. Edit your question to show the results of doing this:

```
python -c "print repr(open('win_ok_file.xml', 'rb').read(200))"
```

which will show unambiguously what is in the first 200 bytes in your file.

Also show us a cut-down version of your code that you have checked will work on Windows to get past the initial error, but reproduces the problem on Linux.

Some assertions, for what they are worth:

- "The file was originally encoded in
  utf-8 and the encoding declared in
  the tag was ascii" ... If the
  encoding in the XML declaration is
  "ascii" but there are non-ASCII
  characters in the file, complying
  parsers should raise an exception.
  Are you sure of what you report?
- The default encoding for XML
  documents is UTF-8. In other words,
  if the encoding is not mentioned in
  the XML declaration, or there is no
  XML declaration at all, the parser is
  required to decode using UTF-8.
- Putting a UTF-8 BOM at the start is
  more likely to hinder than help.
- The XML standard requires parsers to
  accept `CR` as a valid byte in an XML
  document and then immediately pretend
  it didn't exist (except maybe in an
  element with
  `xmlns:space="preserve"`). Changing
  `CR LF` to `LF` is not a good idea.

And some questions: How many bytes in a "quite big" file? Have you considered using `iterparse()` from `xml.etree.cElementTree` or `lxml`?

Comment: I totally forgot to come back here to bring the final answer: the XML were pre-processed by an other part of the code before being fed to the parser. While trying to switch the encoding of the system, I messed up, and the pre-processing operation failed __silently__, leaving the XML untouched and therefore parseable (even if that didn't yield usable results). The XML parser wasn't the issue. Sorry for the noise :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and, instead of trying to parse directly the file like this:

```
document = xmltodict.parse("myfile.xml") # Parse the read document string
```

I parsed it indirectly, by opening previosly the xml document through a object, like this:

```
document_file = open("myfile.xml", "r") # Open a file in read-only mode
original_doc = document_file.read() # read the file object
document = xmltodict.parse(original_doc) # Parse the read document string
```

and it worked.